# Check for very specified numbers padding

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to check for a list of items in my scene to see if they bear 3 (version) paddings at the end of their name - eg. `test_model_001` and if they do, that item will be pass and items that do not pass the condition will be affected by a certain function..

Suppose if my list of items is as follows:

- test_model_01
- test_romeo_005
- test_charlie_rig

I tried and used the following code:

```
eg_list = ['test_model_01', 'test_romeo_005', 'test_charlie_rig']
for item in eg_list:
    mo = re.sub('.*?([0-9]*)$',r'\1', item)
    print mo
```

And it return me `01` and `005` as the output, in which I am hoping it will return me just the `005` only.. How do I ask it to check if it contains 3 paddings? Also, is it possible to include underscore in the check? Is that the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `{3}` to ask for 3 consecutive digits only and prepend underscore:

```
eg_list = ['test_model_01', 'test_romeo_005', 'test_charlie_rig']
for item in eg_list:
    match = re.search(r'_([0-9]{3})$', item)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

This would print `005` only.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in eg_list:
    if re.match(".*_\d{3}$", item):
        print item.split('_')[-1]
```

This matches anything which ends in:
`_` and underscore, `\d` a digit, `{3}` three of them, and `$` the end of the line.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/J09VgczoxIm8zauF)

printing the item, we split it on `_` underscores and take the last value, index `[-1]`

---

The reason `.*?([0-9]*)$` doesn't work is because `[0-9]*` matches 0 or more times, so it can match nothing. This means it will also match `.*?$`, which will match any string.

See the example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lS1rG6/1)

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk after the [0-9] specification means that you are expecting any random number of occurrences of the digits 0-9.  Technically this expression matches test_charlie_rig as well. You can test that out here http://pythex.org/

Replacing the asterisk with a {3} says that you want 3 digits.

```
.*?([0-9]{3})$
```

If you know your format will be close to the examples you showed, you can be a bit more explicit with the regex pattern to prevent even more accidental matches

```
^.+_(\d{3})$
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't like regex unless needed. This should work and be more readable.

```
def name_validator(name, padding_count=3):
    number = name.split("_")[-1]
    if number.isdigit() and number == number.zfill(padding_count):
        return True
    return False

name_validator("test_model_01") # Returns False
name_validator("test_romeo_005") # Returns True
name_validator("test_charlie_rig") # Returns False
```